# My ammap doesnt work for my Nigerian map

Tags: javascript, amcharts, ammap

I'm currently working on the Nigerian map from amCharts and I want the map to read from an external source of which .json is the only format for now. Am using SharePoint 2010 as my server and it doesn't allow me copy .json files so I decided to store my data in the JSON way but in a text file(.txt). The sample (USA) that came with the amCharts documentation works well. But when I change the data and the script to that of the Nigeria map, it doesn't work. Please if you can hep me out. Here is the sample of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
  <html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.css" type="text/css">
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/nigeriaLow.js"></script>
<script src="../dataloader.min.js"></script>
<style>
 body, html {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
</style>
<script>
  var map = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    type: "map",
    "dataLoader": {
      "url": "data/globalrepresentation.txt",
      "showErrors": false
    },
    "colorSteps": 10,
    "areasSettings": {
      "autoZoom": true
    },
    "smallMap": {},
    "valueLegend": {
      "right": 10,
      "minValue": "little",
      "maxValue": "a lot!"
    },
    "responsive": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

And the external document m attaching is this

---

========================================================================

```
{
"map": "nigeriaLow",
"areas"=[{
 { "id":"NG-AB",
 "value": 4447100
 },{ 
 "id":"NG-AD", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-AK", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-AN", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-BA", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-BE", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-BO", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
"id":"NG-BY", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
  "id":"NG-CR", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-DE", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-EB", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-ED", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-EK", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-EN", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-FC", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-GO", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
"id":"NG-IM", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-JI", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-KD", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-KE", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-KN", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-KO", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
"id":"NG-KT", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
"id":"NG-KW", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-LA", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-NA", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-NI", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
"id":"NG-OG", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-ON", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-OS", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-OY", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-PL",
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-RI",
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-SO", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
"id":"NG-TA", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-YO", 
 "value": 4447100
 },{
 "id":"NG-ZA", 
 "value": 4447100

}]
}
```

Comment: You have a JSON syntax error here `"areas"=[{` should be `"areas":[{` (a semicolon instead of `=`)

Comment: i have done the correction and its still not displaying the map!

Comment: Do you get any errors in browser console?

Comment: No i didnt, browser didnt show anything

Comment: Please contact amCharts directly at contact@amcharts.com. This is beyond SO format to troubleshoot like this.